# Directus Flows retunr value

Tags: directus-flows

In a Directus Flow, I want to modify the value of a previous operation in a "Run Script" operation.
What should my "Run Script" operation return?

Tried

```
body = {{ item }}.replace('PARAM', param
return {{ "body" : body }};
```

Tried  also

```
body = data.{{ item }}.replace('PARAM', param
return data;
```

but didn't get a payload for further operations